# Can not insert î (i-circumflex) to MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I can not insert this string `Maître Gims - J'me tire` into `title` column. I get the following error: `sqlstate[hy000]: general error: 1366 incorrect string value: '\xc3 tre ...' for column 'title' at row 1`. Any suggestions? Thanks ;)

`title` has a FULLTEXT index.

`title varchar(200) NOT NULL`

`ENGINE=InnoDB`

`DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

`my.ini`

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

Comment: Please show the complete output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <your_table_name>`.

Comment: @Binarus I wish I still had that table bro. :p